# How do I do a loop while using R

Tags: r

I need to minimize the variable e with a while loop but when I run it it gives me the same initial value I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my code

```
set.seed(123)
d = 0.01
n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(n)
m <- mean(x)
s <- sd(x)
e <- s/sqrt(n)

while (e <= 0.01) {
  n <- n + 1
  x <- c(x, rnorm(1))
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  e <- s/sqrt(n)
}
n
```

Comment: Do you want `while (e>= 0.01)`? As written, your loop will never run because 1/sqrt(1000) isn’t <= 0.01.

Comment: If you use `rnorm` in a question, please include a seed _e.g._ `set.seed(123)` to make the data reproducible.

Comment: You cannot minimize the variable `e` since it will continually decrease. You are selecting random normal numbers with `sd=1` so the values will fluctuate closely around that value. `1/sqrt(n)` will get smaller as `n` gets larger.

Comment: hello zefrilo thanks for your comment, you're right I'm wrongly posing the condition of the while